# Why there is a comma before “and” in a simple sentence of two clauses?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, sentence, conjunctions

> Loretta studied very hard for the test***,*** and she felt confident
> that she would pass.

This is a simple sentence connected with a coordinating conjunction. There should not be a comma because we add a comma only if the number of items is more than two. Why is there a comma here?

Comment: It's not a simple sentence: it's a compound sentence, one with a coordination of two main clauses. The comma is optional in such sentences.

Comment: @BillJ An answer pointing out a flaw in reasoning is still an answer. Please write an answer so that the system knows the question is answered. I doubt sachin will be back now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it mandatory to use a comma before a coordinating conjunction uniting the two independent clauses in a compound sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9239/is-it-mandatory-to-use-a-comma-before-a-coordinating-conjunction-uniting-the-two) or [Do you always need a comma before _and_ when there are two independent clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404534/do-you-always-need-a-comma-before-and-when-there-are-two-independent-clauses)?

Comment: or [Comma before _and_ in compound sentences – necessary or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and-in-compound-sentences-necessary-or-not) Or [Comma before _and_ coordinating two independent clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574894/comma-before-and-coordinating-two-independent-clauses)? @Andrew Leach I don't think one should write an 'answer' for such a multi-duplicate.

Comment: Commas are always optional. And one is very natural there, since it would be audible in speaking.